# Determine how many of total population given statistics of each age group

Tags: percentages, ratio

```
0-14 years old
14% Yes 
25% No
61% Maybe 

15-30 years old
12% Yes
50% No 
38% Maybe 

31-60 years old
20% Yes 
12% No
68% Maybe 

60+ years old
10% Yes 
80% No 
10% Maybe
```

Total population = 132,000,000

I am trying to find out how many people of out the total population choose 'maybe'. May i know are there any Mathematical way to be able to find it?

Answer (score 0):

No.  From the data you have, (almost) all the people could be $0-14$ years, which gives one answer.  They could also be $60+$ years, which gives a different one.  You need to know the number or fraction of the people in each age bracket to answer the question.

Comment: the 0−14 years means years old. 14% Yes, 25% No and 61% Maybe is for within the age group only.

Comment: I understand that.  My point is that if (almost) everybody is young, the whole population is (almost) $61\%$ maybe.  If (almost) everybody is old, the whole population is (almost) $10\%$ maybe.  You don't have the data to tell the difference, so cannot answer the queston.

Comment: Thank you for the insight